# User get 401 when trying to fetch data from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using REST API in my vuejs app to access firebase realtime database, I authenticate users using Google provider and get access token.
Whe I try fetching data using access_token https://rtdb-url/uid/products.json?access_token=[access token] user get 401 error.
But if the user was added to "Users and permissions" in project settings it works.

Rule appplied to RTDB

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      "products": {
        ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
      }
}
```

Comment: Hey add your dabase screenshot or json here l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I just needed to use the access token I got and send it to the following endpoint in the POST body:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=
```

As described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential).